# Join two counts in sql query

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have the sum of next two queries in one query?

```
select COUNT(1) 
from BinaryAssets.BinaryAssetsTags
where TagId = 1731

select COUNT(1) 
from Planning.ScheduleTag
where TagId = 1731
```

Result from first query is 3 for example, from the second 2. I want one query that gives me back 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(select COUNT(1) from BinaryAssets.BinaryAssetsTags where TagId = 1731) 
+ 
(select COUNT(1) from Planning.ScheduleTag where TagId = 1731) 
AS total_sum
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this syntax ,

```
select (select Count(1) from a)+(select Count(1) from b) as 'Total Count'
```